# “Prime conspiracy”'s effect on cryptography

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

Recent news reported about the discovery of a "Prime Conspiracy" which can be read about [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20160313-mathematicians-discover-prime-conspiracy/).

In summary, researchers have discovered that the last digit of prime numbers have a greater predictability than random. The cited example is that primes ending in 9, have a 65% chance of the next prime ending in 1. I am curious if any thought has been generated around the impact this might have to cryptography, namely popular encryption methods like RSA?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/117440/49075 ​ ​ http://mathoverflow.net/q/233633/5810 ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: None. Zero. Zilch. The current season of The Bachelor has a better chance of affecting RSA encryption than this result.

Comment: Actually, it's not that "primes ending in 9 have a 65% chance for the next prime ending in 1", rather it's "for small primes ending in 9, the next prime has a 65% larger chance at ending in 1 than it has to end in 9".